# How to install Nokogiri Gem for Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, jruby, nokogiri

I'm having this problem with nokogiri's gem:

Could not open library 'C:\Ruby187\lib\ruby\gems\1.8\gems\nokogiri-1.4.6-x86-mingw32\ext\nokogiri\libxml2.dll' : unknown

I read that I had to try the 1.5.0.beta3 version. However, when I run

```
C:\Users\t3en4>gem install nokogiri --pre
Fetching: nokogiri-1.5.0.beta.4.gem (100%)
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
        The 'nokogiri' native gem requires installed build tools.

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need [DevKit](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit) to compile the gem properly.

Comment: Ok, now I have it. Now what I have to do?

Comment: Follow the instructions to install it properly and then perform the same `gem install nokogiri --pre` command.

Comment: I get: libxml2 is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokog
iri.html for help with installing dependencies.

Comment: I had to run: C:\DevKit>gem install nokogiri -- --with-xml2-lib --with-xslt-lib --plataform=ruby

Comment: @tiiin4 your answer is much more comprehensive and helpful. You should move it out of the comments and make it an answer in it's own right

Answer (score 9):

wow,
i found the solution, there is a nokogiri for 64bits

goto rubygems, 
goto nokogiri gem, and look at the version list!

https://rubygems.org/gems/nokogiri

notice the x64-mingw32 and x86-mingw32 version

took me hours to figure this out...
[image]

Comment: i think on latest nokogiri, it will auto resolve the correct version via gem install and bundle install