# Why did I get an error whille installing roo gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to use the "roo" gem for accessing contents from files. I tried to install it by entering `gem install roo`, but it resulted in the following error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing roo:
    invalid gem format for C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/cache/nokogiri-1.5.9-x86-mingw32.gem
```

When I tried to install Nokogiri, following error was returned:

```
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    invalid gem format for C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/cache/nokogiri-1.5.9-x86-mingw32.gem
```

How should I resolve it?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455762/how-to-install-nokogiri-gem-for-windows

Comment: Thanks, but I had devkit installed & followed instructions still I'm seeing error : Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'

Comment: `cd C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/cache/`  `del nokogiri-1.5.9-x86-mingw32.gem`  `gem update system`  `gem install roo --include-dependencies`  See if that helps, also ensure that you are installing the correct version 32bit or 64bit etc.